# Function to check which element is before the other

Tags: javascript

How can I create a function that takes 2 elements as arguments and returns the one that is before the other (more up in the HTML code)?

For example, in a document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
    <h1 id="subtitle"></h1>
    <div>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The function would return:

- `head` between `body` and `head`;
- `div` between `div` and `span`;
- `h1#title` between `h1#title` and `h1#subtitle`;
- `false` between `html` and `html`.

Pseudocode example:

```
function firstElement(element1, element2) {
  let elementX = false;
  for ( ... ) {
    if ( ... ) {
      elementX = element1;
    } else {
      elementX = element2;
    }
  }
  return elementX;
}
```

Comment: with jquery, you could check if one of the arguments is a sibling or a parent

Comment: I'm looking for a JavaScript solution which should exist if there's one in JQuery.

Comment: Do you need the one that is first in the DOM, or the on that is shown "before" the other element?

Comment: First in the DOM.

Comment: If there was a way to check a element's position in the document flow or line it would probably make it easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get all Dom elements, place in an array an check the IndexOf..

eg..

Note: I've placed the `all` array part outside the function in case you were requesting lots of DOM checking, for one offs it could be placed inside.

```js
const first = document.querySelector("[data-pos=first]");
const second = document.querySelector("[data-pos=second]");

const all = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("*"));

function firstElement(element1, element2) {
  return all.indexOf(element1) < all.indexOf(element2) ?
    element1 : element2;
}


const found = firstElement(second, first);

found.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
```

```html
<div>test 1</div>
<div>test 2</div>
<div>test 3</div>
<div>test 4</div>
<div data-pos="first">test 5</div>
<div>test 6</div>
<div>test 7</div>
<div>test 8</div>
<div>test 9</div>
<div data-pos="second">test 10</div>
<div>test 11</div>
<div>test 12</div>
```

Comment: Actually a pretty simple and well thought out idea.

Comment: It seems to work. It returns the element instead of false if the elements are the same but that's simple to add. Not sure why make it data-pos instead of id but ok. Thank you for the help! I like that it is simple instead of looping checks for parent, child, previous and next.

Comment: Yeah, tried to keep it as simple as possible, the mods you require for false should be easy.  `Not sure why make it data-pos instead of id`,  I just like to try and avoid global var's as much as possible.